# WCF timout that abort the current operation?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, timeout

I have tried to set sendTimeout, receiveTimeout and the httpRuntim executionTimeout on our WCF (IIS7/TCP/WAS) application service.

The timeout works but the operation will continue to run, what we need is to get the operation aborted.

In this case there could be a deadlock or anything like that and to solve this problem as fast as possible it would be great if we could abort operations that goes on to long, those operations do lock calls from other clients that's why it needs to be aborted.

Comment: Are you catching exception correctly? Because I'm sure something will throw an exception if the connection timed-out.

Comment: I have tried to break on several places and there is no threadabort or anyother exception thrown on the service side when timout is exeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the job on a 'background' thread or use some other mechanism like that and simply ignore the results from the network call based on some 'stop' flag.

I've used a little job system working with tickets based on GUID's that simply did not raise 'Complete' events if the job was stopped.

Aborting the actual network call is potentially unsafe. You might kill a function in some critical networking code path that breaks the driver/os/whatever code.

Comment: Im not following you, Say that a session got a webmethod that is currently waiting on a lock. Now I need to abot this session and abort the currently running thread, is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible but not what you want. Simply ignore the webmethod's result and continue running new actions.
You could run the webmethod on a background thread and Abort it. But who's to say what the webmethod was doing when you aborted it.

Comment: How would he know when to abort it?